# Does anyone have a source reference for Advayavajra in tantric buddhism?

Tags: reference-request, buddhas

This article on tantra -- [Buddhist Tantra - 5](http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=481&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1) -- says

> The deities of the vajrayAna are all manifestations of shUnya.
>   Advayavajra says in a very characteristic verse that the deities are
>   nothing but manifestations of shUnya and are by nature non-existent,
>   and whenever there is manifestation it must be shUnya in essence. The
>   process of evolution of deities from shUnya has four stages: the first
>   is the right perception of the shUnyatA or voidness, the second is its
>   connection with the germ syllable, the third is the conception of an
>   icon and the fourth is the external representation of the deity. This
>   statement which occurs both in the sAdhanamAlA and in advayavajra is a
>   very strong argument against the theory that later Buddhism was
>   nothing but gross idolatry.
>
> They are rather the voluntary manifestations of the shUnya in
>   accordance with the bIjamantras uttered by the worshippers, with an
>   appearance suitable for the function he has to discharge.

Does anyone have the appropiate references to these statements?

Answer (score 1):

If by Advayavajra they mean [Maitripa](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maitripada) then it must come from Maitripa's [Amanasikara](https://www.scribd.com/doc/312268559/A-Fine-Blend-of-Mah%C4%81mudr%C4%81-and-Madhyamaka-Maitr%C4%ABpa-s-Collection-of-Texts-on-Non-conceptual-Realization-Amanasik%C4%81ra).

Specifically, in Mahasukhaprakasa, text #16 in above translation, so pages 181-187.

In addition, for an English translation of a small but relevant part of Sadhanamala see "Two Tantric Meditations: Visualizing the Deity" by Luis O. Gómez. in [Buddhism in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691129681) pages 236-245.